# Is it possible to generalize in this way the definition of the limit of a function between metric spaces at some point?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, metric-spaces

Let $X_{1},X_{2}$ be metric spaces; let $A \subset X_{1}$; let $f: A \to X_{2}$; let $a \in X_{1}$; and let $b \in X_{2}$. Then for $b$ to be the limit of $f$ at $a$, it is required that $a$ is a limit point of $A$ (say baby Rudin, p. 83).

I wonder if it is possible to weaken the requirement by stipulating simply that $a$ is an adherent point of $A$. Thus far I have not yet come up with any reason to reject this possibility.

Lest unnecessary confusion arise, by a limit point of $A$ I mean any point $x \in X_{1}$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ we have $B(x,\delta)\setminus \{x\} \cap A \neq \varnothing$; whereas by an adherent point of $A$ I mean any point $x \in X_{1}$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ we have $B(x,\delta) \cap A \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, we were told about the limits based on adherent points, and it was mostly a convention.

Comment: @Ilya: Thank you for your interest. You may see my revised edition.

Comment: You can generalise in that way. An adherent point of $A$ is either a limit point of $A$, or an isolated point of $A$. In order for $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ to give any information when $a$ is an isolated point of $a$, you have to include the value $f(a)$ in your limit considerations. If you do that only for isolated points, you get something cumbersome and ad-hocish. But if you do it generally, $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $(x\in A \land d(x,a) < \delta) \implies d(f(x),L) < \varepsilon$, that is not new.

Comment: It's a common definition of the limit in some places of the world. Note that for $a\in A$, the only possible limit is then $f(a)$, so for $a\in A$, $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists if and only if $f$ is continuous at $a$. But for $b\in \overline{A}\setminus A$, both definitions are equivalent. And that's the most important situation where one is interested in the limit of a function, so it doesn't matter much which definition one uses.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you. (But it is true that an adherent point of $A$ is either a point of $A$ or a limit point of $A$.)

Comment: I'm not sure about the intention of your parenthetical remark. Every point of $\overline{A}\setminus A$ is clearly a limit point of $A$, and for such points, both definitions coincide. It's the points of $A$ where they differ. At isolated points, one definition says the limit doesn't exist, the other says the limit exists and is the value of $f$ at that point. At points of $A$ that are limit points of $A$, the generalised definition is more restrictive than the one Rudin uses.

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f: A\to X_2$, the standard definition of the statement "the limit of $f$ at $a$ is $b$" does not include any conditions on $a$. In particular, it does not require that $a$ is a limit point of $A$.

If you do make this requirement, then continuity of $f$ is not equivalent to the condition that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$ for all $a\in A$. For instance, the inclusion function $i: \{0\}\hookrightarrow \Bbb R$ is obviously continuous, but under your strict definition, the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} i(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: ? Many books require the condition, say Rudin's analysis. For your reference convenience, see p. 83 of baby Rudin (3rd edition).

Comment: In fact, allowing $a$ to be an adherent point of $A$, instead of a limit point of $A$, does not make things more strict.